# Is it possible to add border outside the margin using CSS?

Tags: css, border, margin

I'm pretty sure someone has asked this question already, but I couldn't find it anywhere on Google or here. I'm just being curious here as to the limitations of CSS regarding this.

Is it possible to add the border of an element outside the margin using CSS? Basically, I want the border to be placed outside of the margin instead of outside the padding.

I understand how the box model works in CSS, for this reason I don't think it's possible to do what I'm asking. However, has anyone found any hacks to go around this?

Thanks!

Comment: We might be able to help you if you share your code with us.

Comment: use a psuedo element

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm jut being curious here about the limitations of CSS, you shouln't have to use a border outside a margin in most cases, but what if you do?

Comment: Using a pseudo element? Like :before and building a box on the space left by the margin?

Comment: I'd go with the pseudo element answer, but an alternative is to use a border instead of a margin e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/255jqv7v/ (this example uses a red border to demonstrate but change it to transparent)

Comment: @Pete: ca8msm is simulating the margin using a border, and simulating the border using an outline. Only issue with that is that outlines aren't affected by layout, so you'd still have to add margins to compensate for the outline - which then become susceptible to margin collapse, similar to the pseudo-element technique.

Comment: You're always going to have the margin collapse problem - that's why you shouldn't put borders outside margins

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with just the element's box since a box is defined by its border edge, not its margin edge, and having borders outside an element's margin edge would interfere with margin collapse.

You could cheat by creating a pseudo-element with your desired border, but IMO it's more trouble than it's worth. The element itself needs to have a margin value equal to your intended margin amount *plus* your desired border width, and the pseudo-element needs to be absolutely positioned with the element as its containing block, and extend out of the box by this sum (assuming you don't want the border to eat into the margins):

```css
html {
    background-color: #fff;
}

body {
    float: left;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ff0;
    margin: 30px;
}

div::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    right: -30px;
    bottom: -30px;
    left: -30px;
    border: 5px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Furthermore, this falls completely apart once you have more than one such element due to margin collapse — and there is no way around this other than to manually adjust specific margins of specific elements to compensate:

```css
html {
    background-color: #fff;
}

body {
    float: left;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ff0;
    margin: 30px;
}

div::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    right: -30px;
    bottom: -30px;
    left: -30px;
    border: 5px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Great explanation! Basically this is as dirty as a solution can go... Thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

I will note that there is 1 small hack using Box-Shadows that you can implement.

A box shadow extends beyond the padding of the object. the "Shadow" by default is the exact size of the box, which you can then shift left/right, up/down.

So for instance, i could have a style of:
`box-shadow : 0 -15px 0 #f7f7f7`

which would give me a '15px border" to the top

This is only useful though if you need 1 side have a border, like if you are using bootstrap and you want the text to be at the 'top' of the bootstrap column but want to encase it in a color, you can extend the background color on top using a box shadow.

Comment: I used this technique perfectly fine to create a border around the whole box like the OP was asking. `box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 13px #000;`

Comment: When adding inset you have a border inside the div which doesn't reduce the amount of space available to the items which was what I wanted.

Comment: This creates a border that eats *into* the margin, but it doesn't create one *outside* the margin at all, which is what the OP was asking. Have I missed something here??